# Swift 3 - How to make UICollectionViewCell same width as label subview

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

How can I make my `UICollectionViewCell` adjust its width with the label contained within the cell?

I have tried about a dozen methods to have the cell adjust its width to the label, but none have worked.

I seriously tried so many different methods to even keep track of it.  Does anyone have an example on how to size `UICollectionViewCells` with the width of a label contained within it?

I have set `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as a delegate, and added

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TagsCollectionViewCell

    //Adding text to the label inside of the cell here

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TagsCollectionViewCell

    //This is called before the creation of the cell

    return CGSize(width: cell.tagLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: cell.tagLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height)
}
```

Comment: You might be able to access the width using the label's `intrinsicContentSize`.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thank you! That seems to get the width and height of my label contained within the cell. However, I added the function CollectionView function `sizeForItemAt`, and pass through the width and height I get from `intrinsicContentSize` and it does not seem to refresh. Is there a good place I should refresh the `CollectionView` at?

Comment: It just needs to happen on the main thread. You can use `DispatchQueue.main.async { refresh goes here }`